# How to generate SAS URLs for blob storage using User Delegation Key in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-security

I'm trying to generate [SAS URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) to read blobs using a [user delegation key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas) and the [Azure SDK for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk-library-api-reference).

The following code works if I use the storage account key but fails if I try to use the user delegation key.

```
import datetime as dt
import json
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlobClient,
    BlobSasPermissions,
    BlobServiceClient,
    generate_blob_sas,
)

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True)
    
storage_acct_name = "XYZ_storage_account"
container_name = "XYZ_blob_container"
blob_name = "xyz_data.json"

url = f"https://{storage_acct_name}.blob.core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(url, credential=credential)
udk = blob_service_client.get_user_delegation_key(
    key_start_time=dt.datetime.utcnow() - dt.timedelta(hours=1),
    key_expiry_time=dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=1))

sas = generate_blob_sas(
    account_name=storage_acct_name,
    container_name=container_name,
    blob_name=blob_name,
    user_delegation_key=udk,
    #account_key=os.getenv("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY"),
    permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
    start = dt.datetime.utcnow() - dt.timedelta(minutes=15),
    expiry = dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=2),
)

sas_url = (
    f'https://{storage_acct_name}.blob.core.windows.net/'
    f'{container_name}/{blob_name}?{sas}'
)

blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)
blob_data = blob_client.download_blob(encoding='UTF-8')
data = json.loads(blob_data.readall())
```

Using the UDK, I get the following error:

“This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
...
ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch”

Having the storage account key floating around is non-ideal for security, so I'd much rather use the UDK.

In the Azure portal, I can view storage account | Access Control (IAM) | View My Access and see that I have role “Contributor”, scope “Subscription (Inherited)”.

It looks like from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas) that “Contributor” should give the require “generateUserDelegationKey” permission, but...

Comment: You would need to assign appropriate storage data related permissions e.g. blob data reader. Please retry after assigning appropriate data role.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, Do you mean that the user calling _get_user_delegation_key_ needs more permissions than those included in the Contributor role?

Comment: Yes. "Contributor" role is a control plane RBAC role i.e. it is used for managing the storage account. To manage data inside a storage account, you would need to assign data related RBAC role - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal.

Comment: Gaurav's answer is correct. Once I got "Storage Blob Data Contributor" the above code worked without a hitch. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Let me post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in order for a SAS token obtained via user delegation key, the user should have appropriate `data` related RBAC role for the storage account.

The reason you got this error is because the user is assigned a `Contributor` role which is a `control plane` RBAC role. Control plane RBAC roles are meant to manage the resources (like storage accounts themselves) and not the data inside them. For managing data, a user must be assigned appropriate data RBAC role.

More information about these roles can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal.