# Deleting files from blob - TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk

I have some files inside a container named **data**:

```
folder1/somepath/folder2/output/folder3/my_file1.csv
folder1/somepath/folder2/output/folder3/my_file4.csv
folder1/somepath/folder2/output/folder3/my_file23.csv
```

I have the following code:

```
file_names_prefix = os.path.join('folder1/somepath/','folder2','output','folder3','my_file')
client = BlobServiceClient('https://mystoragename.blob.core.windows.net',credential=ManagedIdentityCredential()).get_container_client('data')
blob_list = client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=file_names_prefix)
file_list = [blob.name for blob in blob_list]
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
['folder1/somepath/folder2/output/folder3/my_file1.csv',
 'folder1/somepath/folder2/output/folder3/my_file4.csv',
'folder1/somepath/folder2/output/folder3/my_file23.csv']
```

but when trying to delete these files using:

```
client.delete_blobs(file_list)
```

There is an error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> /tmp/ipykernel_2376/712121654.py in 
> ----> 1 client.delete_blobs(file_list)
>
> /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py in wrapper_use_tracer(*args, **kwargs)
> 81             span_impl_type = settings.tracing_implementation()
> 82             if span_impl_type is None:
> ---> 83                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 84
> 85             # Merge span is parameter is set, but only if no explicit parent are passed
>
> /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_container_client.py in delete_blobs(self, *blobs, **kwargs)
> 1298             return iter(list())
> 1299
> -> 1300         reqs, options = self._generate_delete_blobs_options(*blobs, **kwargs)
> 1301
> 1302         return self._batch_send(*reqs, **options)
>
> /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_container_client.py in _generate_delete_blobs_options(self, *blobs, **kwargs)
> 1206             req = HttpRequest(
> 1207                 "DELETE",
> -> 1208                 "/{}/{}{}".format(quote(container_name), quote(blob_name, safe='/~'), self._query_str),
> 1209                 headers=header_parameters
> 1210             )
>
> /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py in quote(string, safe, encoding, errors)
> 817         if errors is not None:
> 818             raise TypeError("quote() doesn't support 'errors' for bytes")
> --> 819     return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
> 820
> 821 def quote_plus(string, safe='', encoding=None, errors=None):
>
> /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py in quote_from_bytes(bs, safe)
> 842     """
> 843     if not isinstance(bs, (bytes, bytearray)):
> --> 844         raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
> 845     if not bs:
> 846         return ''
>
> TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried various things, but nothing worked. Ended up deleting files in a loop.

```
for file in file_list:
    client.delete_blob(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/25764. `delete_blobs` takes `*blobs` as its first argument. So

```py
client.delete_blobs(*file_list)
```

should do the trick.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=storage-py-v12#delete-blobs--blobs----kwargs-) are the official docs for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to lack of permissions. Azure uses Shared Access Singatures[SAS] tokens and roles to protect the Azure Blob storage objects like containers, and blobs. The above code snippet uses default credentials, which has read and list access to the Blob container that is being used, however that user is not having the correct role to delete the blob. Check [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal) to know the RBAC roles that allows blob deletion.

In order to `delete a blob`, the RBAC action that needs to be present for the role is *Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/delete*.

See Azure documentation for full list of [RBAC actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#permissions-for-blob-service-operations)

Refer this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110515/14973743).

Comment: Hi,I tried with updated roles. I am still unable to delete blob files. I am using managed identity in azure function. Plz see the latest edit.

Comment: This error seems to be faced by others, the fix is to pass the `api version` as additional parameter. see the Github discussion [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/16193). When creating BlobServiceClient, pass argument api_version="2019-12-12",  try this and check.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks. I have tried this but sadly it does not work.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of the azure python sdk?